# Срабатывание скрипта через некоторое время

Tags: скрипт, javascript, время

Всем привет!
Есть скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#fullscreen').click(function () {
    var element = document.body;
    var req = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen;
    if(req) {
        req.call(element);
    } else {
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }    
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы он срабатывал скажем через 2 секунды после нажатия?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какое замечательное окончание, возьму на вооружение. Заранее спасибо?

Comment: Всем привет? Есть скрипт? А если найду? Заранее спасибо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это воистину сложно было найти в поисковике ...

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var element = document.body;
        var req = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen;
        if (req) {
            req.call(element);
        } else {
            var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
        return false;
    }, 5000) // время задержки
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Когда же это закончится...

[setTimeout()](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout)

> Этот метод выполняет код (или функцию), указанный в первом аргументе, асинхронно, с задержкой в `delay` миллисекунд.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman сравните себя с учителем и получите ответ на свой вопрос :)

Comment: @Zhukov Roman пожалуйста без нравоучений...

Comment: @Barmaley, я не учу, я ною